# Writing a dict to azure delta table where key and values are store in different column in the delta table

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, delta-lake

I am having a dictionary as {'abc':'123','cde':'456','':'fgh':'789'}. I want to store this into a delta table in databricks . please refer to the image for expected result.
How to achieve this.
I tried converting the dict to pandas df then to pyspark df but i am getting error as
If using all scalar values, you must pass an index